# Problem to run script in .engine format but works fine in .py format

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5, tensorrt

So I do not know how to code very well and I'm stuck at a problem with loading model onto GPU using TensorRT. This is an object detection model and I'm just trying to make it run faster. The script works fine when using Cuda in Pytorch format but when I use engine format after exporting pytorch to engine for tensorRT these errors occur.

```
[04/05/2023-19:41:54] [TRT] [I] [MemUsageChange] Init CUDA: CPU +499, GPU +0, now: CPU 11536, GPU 1240 (MiB)
[04/05/2023-19:41:54] [TRT] [I] Loaded engine size: 5 MiB
[04/05/2023-19:41:55] [TRT] [I] [MemUsageChange] Init cuDNN: CPU +1186, GPU +408, now: CPU 12783, GPU 1654 (MiB)
[04/05/2023-19:41:55] [TRT] [I] [MemUsageChange] TensorRT-managed allocation in engine deserialization: CPU +0, GPU +0, now: CPU 0, GPU 0 (MiB)
[04/05/2023-19:41:55] [TRT] [I] [MemUsageChange] Init cuDNN: CPU +0, GPU +8, now: CPU 12776, GPU 1654 (MiB)
[04/05/2023-19:41:55] [TRT] [I] [MemUsageChange] TensorRT-managed allocation in IExecutionContext creation: CPU +0, GPU +0, now: CPU 0, GPU 0 (MiB)
Adding AutoShape... 
(1376, 576, 2064, 864)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\HALLÅÅ\Documents\CHEATS\scripts\main copy.py", line 150, in <module>
    df= model(screenshot, size=640).pandas().xyxy[0]
  File "C:\Users\HALLÅÅ\Documents\CHEATS\cheats-env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HALLÅÅ\Documents\CHEATS\cheats-env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HALLÅÅ\Documents\CHEATS\yolov5\models\common.py", line 704, in forward
    y = self.model(x, augment=augment)  # forward
  File "C:\Users\HALLÅÅ\Documents\CHEATS\cheats-env\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\HALLÅÅ\Documents\CHEATS\yolov5\models\common.py", line 536, in forward
    assert im.shape == s, f"input size {im.shape} {'>' if self.dynamic else 'not equal to'} max model size {s}"
AssertionError: input size torch.Size([1, 3, 288, 640]) not equal to max model size (1, 3, 640, 640)
```

Answer (score 0):

The model got square-like input. So make your image size 640x640.

If you want to lower the image size to 320x320 (for example), you need to retrain the model with this size.